# Is the below expression valid in Yacc

Tags: yacc

In Yacc(or bison)  , is the below expression a syntactically valid one ?

```
sentence :  noun verb {
/* some action here which uses only $1 , $2 */ 
} 
predicate {
/*some action which uses $1,$2,$3,$4 */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid.

The first action is a mid-rule action. It itself has a semantic value, which will be $3, so the comment in the second action should include $4 (the value of `predicate`).

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) . Could you please throw light on the semantic value of the first-action ?   i.e what exactly is the value returned by the action and what is its type
and Can you suggest a reference book for yacc ?

Comment: @Percy: you give it a value by assigning to `$$`, but since you need to declare a type as well, you normally use the explicit type syntax `$<tag>$`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions.html. As for books, read the  manual or find a copy of John Levine's book, preferably the newer one.